# From Laravel I got failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel 5.4 and got the error at Web Server as below

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/github/myweb/monitor/storage/framework/views/b38c71581503e85762ce2fe49a8bis726b1164d9.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied n /github/myweb/monitor/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]:

When I tested on local every thing is fine, but after pushing code to server, i am getting error for path `'/github/myweb/'` where it's from. I want path like this

`/var/www/master/monitor`

How to remove prefix `'/github/myweb/'` from path I don't know where it's from

What Is wrong?

Comment: which means that you need to 755 permission to strorage directory(Recursively)

Answer (score 13):

First Clear your Cache,

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

And Then Run `sudo chmod -R 755 storage/`

Alternatively you can delete your bootstrap/cache/config.php

Comment: No, do not give 777 permissions to any folder

Comment: This worked for me, in a development environment, so. Dazzle, How to solve this issue without giving 777 permissions?

Comment: you have to give permission on production as well

Comment: update,.. How to solve this issue without giving 777 permissions?

Comment: You can add 755 to storage in production.

Comment: @AbingPj Give 755 instead of 777

Comment: @VickyGill 755 instead of 777 didn't work for me

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You absolutely do not want to grant write access to executable or system files to all users under any circumstances. You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably `chmod 755`) and learn about the Unix permissions model before you try to use it again. If this happened on a system with Internet access, check whether an intruder could have exploited this to escalate their privileges. For scenarios where 755 doesn't work, understand what the numbers mean, then take it from there.

Answer (score 4):

If you cd into your app, you will probably see that some folders have the "www-data" user or group.

If you are using Laravel Forge, to fix this, you want to change the user and group to "forge".

Instead of cd'ing into every directory and running this on every file and folder, you can do this recursively with the -R flag.

```
sudo chown -R forge:forge storage
```

Now you can get back to making progress !

Answer (score 1):

Try out:
**php artisan view:clear**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what I did is correct but I changed the owner and group of the cache folder to match the rest of the app

```
# cd /var/www/html/snipeit/storage/framework
# chown -R snipeitapp:www-data cache/
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cached bootstrap files (events, views, cache, route, config, compiled):

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```