# Apache - Server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, centos7

I have deployed my Laravel application in CentOS7,Apache and LAMP. Created two subdomains and mapped the directories like as below

**Subdomains**

- abc.example.com -> /var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/public
- xyz.example.com -> /var/www/xyz.example.com/public_html/public

**Virtual Host Configuration**

Created virtual host configuration files for each subdomain. For example for abc.example.com created the file in /etc/conf.d/abc.example.com.conf

and in /var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/.htaccess having the following entries.

**public_html/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect All Requests To The Subfolder
RewriteRule ^ /public
```

and in /var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/public/.htaccess having the following entries.

**public_html/public/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

also, index.php (/abc.example.com/public_html/index.php) contains laravel's default code as below

```html
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

While browsing http://abc.example.com forbidder error is displaying
[image]

Also, error.log file is logging the following exception as below.

```
AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/public/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Comment: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found !!!
Add index.html file or set specific DirectoryIndex 
`DirectoryIndex index.html index.php`

Comment: Question updated with index.php file. Please check @MaximColesnic

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]` in root .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

> also, index.php (`/abc.example.com/public_html/index.php`) contains laravel's default code as below

According to your other directives, the `index.php` file should be inside the `/public_html/public` subdirectory, not `/public_html`.

Also, you do need to make sure that the `DirectoryIndex` is correctly set. The server *default* is `index.html` only. For example, at the top of `/public/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: It is showing index.php file after did the recommended settings.

Comment: That's great. In that case, please accept the answer to help other readers and to remove the question from the unanswered question queue. Thanks, much appreciated. :)

Comment: I meant it is displaying raw view of index.php, still I need help

Comment: By "raw view of index.php", you mean the unprocessed PHP code is sent to the client?!

Comment: Yes, it should redirect to the login page instead of that it is displaying the raw view of index.php which was enclosed in my question above.

Comment: I reinstalled PHP, got the error " PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/storage/framework/views/838e216fb3c2be1dfa7ee2aa9641685422bf723d.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in" then I follow the steps mentioned in the first answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55448836/from-laravel-i-got-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied it is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

You need to authorize the directory containing your code
You can try this command:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/
sudo find /var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/storage/
```

Comment: Please check my previous comments under MrWhite's answer.