# Found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directiv Codeigniter on shared hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, cpanel, shared-hosting

I am facing issue while installing the codeigniter on shared hosting. My hosting directory is like this:
`/public_html/siteFolder

During installation I am facing issue with public folder that's giving me 500 error

> Cannot serve directory /home4/user234/public_html/siteFolder/: No
> matching DirectoryIndex
> (index.html.var,index.htm,index.html,index.shtml,index.xhtml,index.wml,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.js,index.jp,index.php4,index.php3,index.php,index.phtml,default.htm,default.html,home.htm,index.php5,Default.html,Default.htm,home.html)
> found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options
> directive

I tried to edit `.htaccess` but it's not working. Here is my `.htaccess` file.

```
    # Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
    

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: maybe this post can give you more insights: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66661597/apache-server-generated-directory-index-forbidden-by-options-directive.

Comment: "while installing" - Have you actually installed codeigniter or is this an issue during installation? Is _everything_ in the `/siteFolder` subdirectory?

Comment: everything is in `/siteFolder`. it's during installation